# Are the time_to_batch and batch_time functions of the Tensorflow implementation of WaveNet necessary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Deepmind recently created a new type of convolutional architecture called WaveNet. The main innovation of WaveNet is dilated convolutions. This question is not about the modelling done, but rather about a specific programming technique they used.
The Tensorflow implementation of WaveNet can be found [here](https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet).
My question concerns some code found in the file 'ops.py'
Two functions, in particular are:

```
def time_to_batch(value, dilation, name=None):
    with tf.name_scope('time_to_batch'):
        shape = tf.shape(value)
        pad_elements = dilation - 1 - (shape[1] + dilation - 1) % dilation
        padded = tf.pad(value, [[0, 0], [0, pad_elements], [0, 0]])
        reshaped = tf.reshape(padded, [-1, dilation, shape[2]])
        transposed = tf.transpose(reshaped, perm=[1, 0, 2])
        return tf.reshape(transposed, [shape[0] * dilation, -1, shape[2]])


def batch_to_time(value, dilation, name=None):
    with tf.name_scope('batch_to_time'):
        shape = tf.shape(value)
        prepared = tf.reshape(value, [dilation, -1, shape[2]])
        transposed = tf.transpose(prepared, perm=[1, 0, 2])
        return tf.reshape(transposed,
                          [tf.div(shape[0], dilation), -1, shape[2]])
```

The functions are then called by some other code as in:

```
def causal_conv(value, filter_, dilation, name='causal_conv'):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        filter_width = tf.shape(filter_)[0]
        if dilation > 1:
            transformed = time_to_batch(value, dilation)
            conv = tf.nn.conv1d(transformed, filter_, stride=1,
                                padding='VALID')
            restored = batch_to_time(conv, dilation)
        else:
            restored = tf.nn.conv1d(value, filter_, stride=1, padding='VALID')
        # Remove excess elements at the end.
        out_width = tf.shape(value)[1] - (filter_width - 1) * dilation
        result = tf.slice(restored,
                          [0, 0, 0],
                          [-1, out_width, -1])
        return result
```

So clearly batch_to_time and time_to_batch are only called when dilation is greater than 1. I don't quite understand how these functions work (I am still trying to learn Tensorflow) but they must squish the input down depending on the dilation, apply a regular convolution, then un-squish it back.
However, I noticed the API provides a function called [atrous_conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/atrous_conv2d). An atrous convolution is another name for a dilated convolution.

So finally, I am ready to ask my question!

Are the aforementioned reshaping functions required, or can the dilated convolutions be achieved using atrous_conv2D with one of the dimensions set to size 1?

After all, conv1D is implemented by calling conv2D. From [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv1d)  :"Internally, this op reshapes the input tensors and invokes tf.nn.conv2d"

Comment: TensorFlow's support for dilated convolutions came largely in response to WaveNet. WaveNet itself likely just hasn't be updated to rely on the TensorFlow reshapes. If you're writing new code I would suggest using the TensorFlow functions unless you need the flexibility for some reason.

Comment: So that's what it is! I thought they were doing something clever to somehow make the convolutions more efficient, but it turns out it's just because it was written in the absence of dilation support.

Comment: @AllenLavoie If you are feeling generous (and want some of those sweet reputation points) please consider giving us a demo of how to rewrite the causal_conv function using atrous_conv2d without time_to_batch etc.